# Python mixing global and local variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, variable-assignment

I initialize a global variable 'i' to 0 and a function definition.
In the def, I want to initialize local 'j' to global 'i' and then assign 1 to global 'i', but the compliler thinks when I assign 1 to 'i', I initialize it.

this is not working:

```
i = 0
def doSomething():
    j = i # compiler throws UnboundLocalError here
    i = 1
```

and this is working:

```
i = 0
def doSomething():
    j = i
```

Comment: An assignment to a variable anywhere in a function body makes that variable *local*

Comment: I would paraphrase a title "Python mixing global and local variable?" to "Why is Python protecting from using a global and local variable?". The answer is "Because you shouldn't ".

Comment: Short answer, without explicit `global var`, `var` is readonly in local scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the global variable within the function before modifying.

```
 i = 0
def doSomething():
    global i #needed to modify the global variable.
    j = i # compiler throws UnboundLocalError here
    i = 1
```